# This is a question about Orange3

Tags: orange

When I open Predictions in orange3, there is a pink mark under the output material and output material, and I wonder if it is expressed as a percentage value.
When you look at the data table in the widget, it is represented as Color by instance classes.
I'm also curious about what this means.
I'd appreciate it if you could answer.[image]